# Using `stringr` to detect specific words in a list

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am working with some data that looks like this:

```
GameID EventID Route                                        
    <int>   <int> <chr>                                        
 1   2793      15 Fade - Back Shoulder, Curl, Go/Fly, Out, Curl
 2   2793      25 Go/Fly, Curl, Dig, Check & Release           
 3   2793      45 Fade, Swing - Left, Slant, Dig, Curl         
 4   2793      50 Jet Sweep Pass, Swing - Right                
 5   2793      55 Corner, Curl, Post, Curl, Slant              
 6   2793      60 Sluggo, Post, Curl, Chip - Flat, Flat - Left 
 7   2793      65 Go/Fly, Seam, Deep Cross, Dig, Flat - Right  
 8   2793      70 Curl, Dig, Post, Chip - Flat                 
 9   2793      85 Curl, Seam, Curl, Dig, Curl                  
10   2793      95 Screen - RB
```

I am attempting to use `str_detect` to find the groups within the `Routes` column.

For example:

```
tare.route <- route.data %>%
  filter(str_detect(Route, "Slant" & "Fade"))
```

However, when doing so, I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
i Input `..1` is `str_detect(Route, "Slant" & "Fade")`.
```

Basically, I am trying to use the above code to pull out every `Route` observation that includes **JUST** the words I am searching for (and they do not have to be in the same order as listed in the data ... they just *simply have to be included*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE OF THE DATA**

```
structure(list(GameID = c(2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2794L, 2794L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 
2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2795L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 
2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L, 2796L), EventID = c(15L, 
25L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 65L, 70L, 85L, 95L, 100L, 110L, 115L, 
135L, 155L, 160L, 170L, 175L, 180L, 185L, 200L, 210L, 225L, 235L, 
255L, 290L, 295L, 305L, 320L, 340L, 345L, 350L, 355L, 360L, 365L, 
370L, 380L, 385L, 415L, 425L, 440L, 445L, 465L, 480L, 500L, 515L, 
525L, 530L, 545L, 565L, 570L, 580L, 610L, 625L, 630L, 635L, 645L, 
660L, 665L, 675L, 700L, 715L, 720L, 725L, 730L, 735L, 805L, 810L, 
25L, 30L, 45L, 60L, 65L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 95L, 105L, 115L, 120L, 
135L, 140L, 155L, 160L, 170L, 190L, 205L, 215L, 260L, 265L, 275L, 
285L, 290L, 295L, 300L, 310L, 325L, 330L, 350L, 355L, 380L, 390L, 
405L, 415L, 435L, 440L, 445L, 450L, 455L, 495L, 500L, 505L, 515L, 
525L, 540L, 565L, 575L, 580L, 600L, 615L, 620L, 625L, 635L, 645L, 
650L, 655L, 665L, 670L, 695L, 700L, 715L, 720L, 725L, 730L, 735L, 
755L, 760L, 770L, 775L, 780L, 785L, 790L, 795L, 810L, 815L, 830L, 
855L, 860L, 865L, 870L, 875L, 880L, 890L, 900L, 905L, 910L, 920L, 
925L, 940L, 945L, 15L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 55L, 75L, 100L, 120L, 135L, 
145L, 165L, 180L, 210L, 225L, 230L, 235L, 260L, 265L, 275L, 290L, 
295L, 300L, 320L, 325L, 345L, 360L, 370L, 380L, 390L, 400L, 410L, 
415L, 420L, 425L, 430L, 465L, 470L, 485L, 505L, 515L, 520L, 525L, 
540L, 545L, 560L, 580L, 585L, 600L, 605L, 610L, 615L, 620L, 630L, 
635L, 645L, 650L, 660L, 680L, 720L, 725L, 730L, 740L, 755L, 760L, 
785L, 805L, 840L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 95L, 
100L, 130L, 135L, 140L, 150L, 160L, 175L, 185L, 215L, 220L, 235L, 
245L, 250L, 260L, 275L, 280L, 285L, 290L, 305L, 330L, 335L, 340L, 
345L, 350L, 380L, 385L, 395L, 405L, 420L, 425L, 435L, 440L, 465L, 
495L, 500L, 510L, 515L, 520L, 535L, 545L, 555L, 560L, 580L, 595L, 
600L, 615L, 635L, 645L, 665L, 680L, 685L, 690L, 695L, 700L, 710L, 
715L, 725L, 730L, 745L, 755L, 775L, 780L, 785L, 790L), Route = c("Fade - Back Shoulder, Curl, Go/Fly, Out, Curl", 
"Go/Fly, Curl, Dig, Check & Release", "Fade, Swing - Left, Slant, Dig, Curl", 
"Jet Sweep Pass, Swing - Right", "Corner, Curl, Post, Curl, Slant", 
"Sluggo, Post, Curl, Chip - Flat, Flat - Left", "Go/Fly, Seam, Deep Cross, Dig, Flat - Right", 
"Curl, Dig, Post, Chip - Flat", "Curl, Seam, Curl, Dig, Curl", 
"Screen - RB", "Flat - Right, Fade, Out, Fade, Out", "Curl, Flat - Left, Dig", 
"Deep Cross, Screen - Bubble, Post, Run Fake", "Curl, Curl, Curl", 
"Swing - Left, Screen - TE, Screen - Bubble", "Curl, Flat - Left, Curl, Flat - Right", 
"Flat - Right, Slant, Slant, Run Fake", "Run Fake, Beneath, Fade", 
"Flat - Left, Swing - Right, Comeback, Deep Cross", "Curl, Post, Slant, Drag, Flat - Left", 
"Swing - Right, Run Fake, Slant", "Curl, Fade, Dig, Dig, Flat - Right", 
"Curl, Chip - Flat, Curl, Chip - Flat", "Chip - Drag, Go/Fly, Out, Dig, Chip - Flat", 
"Curl, Slant, Flat - Left, Curl, Wheel", "Drag, Curl, Deep Cross, Drag, Flat - Left", 
"Whip, Whip, Corner", "Screen - Tunnel, Run Fake", "Wheel, Deep Cross, Beneath, Run Fake, Seam", 
"Post, Curl, Fade, Out, Chip - Flat", "Dig, Seam, Corner, Drag, Dig", 
"Curl, Drag, Drag, Out, Swing - Left", "Dig, Dig, Fade, Out", 
"Check & Release, Go/Fly, Seam, Fade, Seam", "Curl, Post, Drag, Out, Chip - Curl", 
"Dig, Post, Curl, Go/Fly", "Curl, Slant, Slant, Corner, Swing - Right", 
"Go/Fly, Corner, Out, Curl", "Fade, Out, Run Fake", "Slant, Slant, Dig, Out, Out", 
"Screen - Bubble, Slant, Flat - Right", "Post, Wheel, Swing - Left, Post, Seam", 
"Swing - Left, Dig, Run Fake", "Slant, Curl, Seam, Slant, Swing - Left", 
"Out, Post, Out, Deep Cross, Check & Release", "Flat - Right, Swing - Left, Drag, Out", 
"Dig, Flat - Left, Fade, Curl, Check & Release", "Dig, Deep Cross, Dig, Drag, Flat - Left", 
"Drag, Deep Cross, Seam, Fade, Swing - Left", "Whip, Fade, Seam, Curl, Post", 
"Dig, Out, Post, Drag", "Out, Out, Run Fake", "Over Ball, Pick, Drag, Curl, Swing - Right", 
"Seam, Curl, Out, Slant, Fade", "Fade, Curl, Fade, Curl, Check & Release", 
"Dig, Curl, Out, Fade, Fade", "Out, Go/Fly, Dig, Dig, Out", "Out, Flat - Right, Fade, Fade, Chip - Flat", 
"Out, Curl, Out, Out", "Curl, Drag, Fade, Seam, Seam", "Curl, Drag, Corner, Slant, Flat - Left", 
"Out, Fade, Fade, Go/Fly, Curl", "Go/Fly, Out, Post, Out, Hitch & Go", 
"Curl, Slant, Fade, Screen - Tunnel", "Curl, Corner, Dig, Slant, Post", 
"Out, Corner, Corner, Dig, Slant", "Dig, Out, Fade, Seam, Curl", 
"Curl, Post, Curl, Fade, Curl", "Curl, Dig, Corner, Drag, Flat - Right", 
"Check & Release, Corner, Chip - Flat, Dig, Chip - Flat", "Curl, Curl, Curl, Out, Chip - Flat", 
"Deep Cross, Corner, Run Fake, Whip, Run Fake", "Dig, Go/Fly, Post, Go/Fly, Dig", 
"Chip - Flat, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Out, Slant", "Post, Wheel, Drag, Dig, Swing - Left", 
"Screen - RB, Slant, Beneath", "Flat - Right, Fade, Go/Fly, Drag, Dig", 
"Curl, Comeback, Curl, Slant, Slant", "Screen - Quick", "Beneath, Drag, Corner, Flat - Right", 
"Whip, Post", "Comeback, Deep Cross, Flat - Left", "Go/Fly, Out, Curl, Dig, Flat - Right", 
"Flat - Left, Slant, Curl, Dig, Flat - Right", "Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Fade, Dig, Screen - RB", 
"Flat - Left, Curl, Deep Cross", "Out, Curl, Curl, Out", "Check & Release, Fade, Screen - Quick, Curl", 
"Slant, Curl, Curl, Corner, Swing - Right", "Go/Fly, Curl, Go/Fly, Curl, Check & Release", 
"Flat - Left, Deep Cross, Whip, Chip - Flat, Corner", "Slant, Curl, Go/Fly, Flat - Right", 
"Deep Cross, Curl, Post, Screen - RB", "Screen - Tunnel, Swing - Left", 
"Out, Drag, Dig, Fade", "Drag, Drag, Seam, Flat - Right", "Swing - Left, Deep Cross, Slant, Deep Cross, Go/Fly", 
"Corner, Curl, Curl, Curl, Flat - Right", "Curl, Curl, Flat - Left, Corner, Flat - Right", 
"Check & Release, Dig, Deep Cross, Deep Cross, Drag", "Curl, Post, Out, Seam, Quick", 
"Swing - Left, Go/Fly, Drag, Go/Fly, Out", "Out, Curl, Over Ball, Out, Check & Release", 
"Dig, Curl, Fade, Flat - Right, Swing - Left", "Curl, Curl, Curl, Curl, Curl", 
"Chip - Flat, Post, Curl, Fade", "Curl, Flat - Right, Corner, Flat - Left, Corner", 
"Check & Release, Curl, Dig, Dig, Flat - Right", "Dig, Flat - Left, Curl, Slant, Pick", 
"Beneath, Deep Cross, Dig, Flat - Left", "Quick, Seam, Out, Go/Fly", 
"Post, Slant, Go/Fly, Drag", "Hitch & Go, Curl, Post, Drag, Angle", 
"Post, Seam, Deep Cross, Flat - Left, Chip - Drag", "Seam, Post, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Drag", 
"Check & Release, Drag, Out, Dig, Dig", "Screen - RB, Go/Fly, Deep Cross", 
"Chip - Curl, Dig, Dig, Out, Out", "Flat - Right, Post, Out, Curl, Seam", 
"Flat - Right, Out, Dig, Sluggo, Curl", "Corner, Screen - RB, Flat - Right", 
"Run Fake, Slant, Screen - Bubble, Slant", "Go/Fly, Curl, Seam, Go/Fly, Out", 
"Flat - Right, Corner, Curl, Over Ball", "Flat - Left, Deep Cross, Go/Fly", 
"Run Fake, Deep Cross, Deep Cross", "Screen - Quick", "Wheel, Go/Fly, Drag, Go/Fly", 
"Seam, Go/Fly, Chip - Drag, Drag, Chip - Flat", "Slant, Slant, Post, Slant", 
"Angle, Dig, Post, Out, Drag", "Swing - Right, Corner, Out, Dig, Curl", 
"Check & Release, Curl, Out, Over Ball, Curl", "Dig, Seam, Dig, Dig, Corner", 
"Flat - Right, Corner, Flat - Left, Corner, Curl", "Wheel, Drag, Curl, Drag, Go/Fly", 
"Drag, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Seam, Chip - Flat", "Comeback, Dig, Flat - Left, Dig, Post", 
"Slant, Over Ball, Slant, Slant, Flat - Left", "Out, Corner, Curl, Dig, Check & Release", 
"Curl, Flat - Right, Dig, Curl, Seam", "Drag, Out, Out, Drag", 
"Curl, Dig, Out, Curl", "Slant, Out, Go/Fly, Flat - Left, Sluggo", 
"Post Corner, Whip, Drag, Beneath, Run Fake", "Go/Fly, Run Fake, Slant, Chip - Flat, Chip - Flat", 
"Corner, Curl, Dig, Post, Out", "Out, Go/Fly, Post, Swing - Right, Curl", 
"Curl, Slant, Flat - Right, Slant, Curl", "Corner, Chip - Flat, Corner, Chip - Flat, Curl", 
"Curl, Post, Comeback, Curl, Seam", "Go/Fly, Curl, Post, Chip - Flat, Out", 
"Slant, Flat - Left, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Screen - RB", "Curl, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Seam", 
"Flat - Right, Corner, Curl, Dig, Swing - Left", "Dig, Curl, Corner, Flat - Right, Swing - Left", 
"Dig, Curl, Corner, Drag, Flat - Left", "Dig, Whip, Stick - Nod, Drag, Flat - Left", 
"Seam, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Curl", "Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Deep Cross", 
"Curl, Curl, Curl, Curl, Out", "Curl, Seam, Curl, Seam, Over Ball", 
"Go/Fly, Over Ball, Dig, Flat - Right, Angle", "Slant, Chip - Curl, Slant, Flat - Right", 
"Screen - Bubble, Run Fake", "Drag, Flat - Right, Dig, Drag", 
"Go/Fly, Out, Dig, Go/Fly, Out", "Wheel, Drag, Post, Deep Cross, Curl", 
"Corner, Post", "Curl, Dig, Out, Seam, Curl", "Corner, Beneath, Run Fake", 
"Curl, Corner, Chip - Drag, Flat - Left", "Go/Fly, Out, Dig, Slant, Seam", 
"Go/Fly, Post", "Dig, Drag, Out, Go/Fly", "Beneath, Drag, Chip - Curl, Corner, Run Fake", 
"Post, Curl, Curl, Post, Curl", "Dig, Dig, Seam, Go/Fly, Out", 
"Dig, Post, Deep Cross, Chip - Drag", "Flat - Right, Out, Curl, Out", 
"Drag, Corner, Corner, Run Fake", "Fade, Deep Cross, Seam, Chip - Drag", 
"Curl, Comeback, Dig, Run Fake", "Go/Fly, Fade, Dig, Over Ball, Wheel", 
"Corner, Chip - Flat, Curl, Out, Curl", "Slant, Dig, Out, Fade, Curl", 
"Go/Fly, Dig, Out, Go/Fly, Chip - Curl", "Wheel, Whip, Curl, Flat - Left, Whip", 
"Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Seam, Seam, Angle", "Curl, Corner, Flat - Left, Curl, Dig", 
"Seam, Deep Cross, Angle, Go/Fly, Comeback", "Drag, Corner, Post, Dig, Flat - Right", 
"Fade, Seam, Fade, Seam, Curl", "Out, Pick, Out, Deep Cross", 
"Fade, Fade, Seam, Seam", "Slant, Slant, Fade, Out, Out", "Curl, Slant, Flat - Left, Corner, Curl", 
"Post, Go/Fly, Curl, Flat - Left", "Out, Curl, Dig, Flat - Left, Comeback", 
"Drag, Chip - Seam, Out, Post, Curl", "Go/Fly, Out, Chip - Drag, Go/Fly, Out", 
"Dig, Seam, Curl, Dig", "Chip - Drag, Dig, Go/Fly, Dig", "Go/Fly, Swing - Right, Sluggo, Curl, Dig", 
"Go/Fly, Dig, Deep Cross, Drag, Wheel", "Out, Corner, Chip - Flat", 
"Chip - Flat, Post Corner, Corner, Dig", "Out, Go/Fly, Dig, Drag, Curl", 
"Post, Curl, Deep Cross, Out", "Curl, Go/Fly, Go/Fly, Deep Cross, Go/Fly", 
"Deep Cross, Slant, Screen - RB", "Slant, Dig, Corner, Drag", 
"Out, Corner, Drag, Drag", "Go/Fly, Out & Up, Chip - Flat, Dig, Chip - Drag", 
"Deep Cross, Beneath, Corner, Flat - Right, Run Fake", "Go/Fly, Out, Drag, Curl, Go/Fly", 
"Whip, Curl, Post, Post, Curl", "Curl, Swing - Right, Fade, Seam, Seam", 
"Dig, Dig, Post, Go/Fly, Check & Release", "Curl, Seam, Out, Curl, Curl", 
"Out, Out, Out, Out, Curl", "Dig, Dig, Go/Fly", "Curl, Corner, Curl, Corner, Seam", 
"Slant, Slant, Go/Fly, Flat - Right, Curl", "Out, Drag, Slant, Out, Out", 
"Drag, Corner, Corner, Post", "Slant, Slant, Slant, Seam, Flat - Right", 
"Drag, Dig, Corner, Out", "Dig, Out, Dig, Check & Release", "Out, Out, Go/Fly, Curl, Swing - Right", 
"Go/Fly, Curl, Curl, Go/Fly, Curl", "Curl, Seam, Dig, Dig", "Out, Post, Out, Quick", 
"Curl, Swing - Left, Curl", "Post, Slant, Fade, Run Fake", "Go/Fly, Wheel, Screen - TE, Run Fake", 
"Curl, Post Corner, Whip, Corner, Curl", "Fade, Seam, Curl, Fade, Whip", 
"Deep Cross, Go/Fly, Deep Cross", "Curl, Dig, Curl, Curl", "Go/Fly, Screen - Bubble, Screen - RB", 
"Curl, Dig, Deep Cross, Swing - Right, Curl", "Fade, Seam, Out, Corner, Flat - Right", 
"Fade, Chip - Flat, Dig, Curl", "Dig, Deep Cross, Drag, Corner, Swing - Right", 
"Post, Go/Fly, Chip - Flat, Curl, Swing - Right", "Out, Curl, Post, Out, Out", 
"Go/Fly, Fade, Comeback, Check & Release", "Angle, Go/Fly, Deep Cross, Go/Fly, Go/Fly", 
"Swing - Right, Dig, Screen - RB", "Curl, Curl, Swing - Left", 
"Run Fake, Out, Fade, Curl, Curl", "Angle, Out, Curl, Go/Fly, Check & Release", 
"Go/Fly, Swing - Left, Screen - RB", "Screen - Quick, Slant, Screen - Tunnel, Run Fake", 
"Dig, Dig, Dig, Seam, Swing - Left", "Curl, Go/Fly, Dig, Go/Fly", 
"Out, Dig, Out, Curl, Flat - Right", "Screen - Quick, Out, Run Fake", 
"Go/Fly, Slant, Drag, Curl", "Swing - Left, Deep Cross, Flat - Right", 
"Drag, Deep Cross, Deep Cross, Swing - Left, Angle", "Whip, Corner Post, Whip, Corner, Curl", 
"Go/Fly, Out & Up, Curl, Quick, Drag", "Out, Go/Fly, Deep Cross, Dig", 
"Screen - Bubble", "Chip - Flat, Out, Go/Fly, Go/Fly", "Dig, Dig, Curl, Over Ball, Out", 
"Screen - Quick, Screen - Tunnel", "Go/Fly, Out, Go/Fly", "Dig, Fade, Drag", 
"Screen - Quick, Screen - Quick, Run Fake", "Screen - RB, Go/Fly, Curl, Out, Flat - Right", 
"Comeback, Dig, Dig", "Chip - Flat, Drag, Curl, Go/Fly, Angle", 
"Check & Release, Dig, Out & Up, Seam, Out", "Curl, Go/Fly, Post, Comeback, Out", 
"Check & Release, Go/Fly, Seam, Go/Fly, Out", "Fade, Curl, Curl, Comeback, Flat - Right", 
"Out, Post, Whip, Deep Cross, Dig", "Quick, Screen - Bubble", 
"Go/Fly, Curl, Curl, Seam, Curl", "Check & Release, Dig, Curl, Post, Dig", 
"Drag, Curl, Out, Drag, Wheel", "Swing - Left, Corner, Out, Dig, Curl", 
"Swing - Right, Slant, Screen - TE", "Swing - Left, Fade, Screen - RB", 
"Check & Release, Corner, Curl, Out", "Jet Sweep Pass, Run Fake", 
"Drag, Comeback, Dig, Post, Chip - Seam", "Flat - Right, Curl, Curl, Curl, Fade", 
"Chip - Curl, Dig, Out, Slant, Slant", "Run Fake, Beneath, Beneath, Deep Cross, Chip", 
"Slant, Dig, Dig, Slant, Flat - Right", "Post, Post, Quick", 
"Dig, Dig, Curl, Drag, Out", "Curl, Dig, Curl, Seam, Whip", "Chip - Flat, Curl, Go/Fly, Curl, Dig", 
"Run Fake, Deep Cross, Chip - Flat, Corner", "Jet Sweep Pass, Run Fake"
)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

If searching for routes that include JUST slants & fades, I'd like the outcome to look like this:

```
GameID      EventID      Route
1234        1234         Slant, Slant, Fade
```

... and then so on and so forth for every EventID that includes just Slants and Fades.

Comment: Try `"\\b(Slant|Fade)\\b"`

Comment: That is returning every `Route' observation that has either 'Slant' or 'Fade' included in it. I am trying to locate just those 'Route' observation that was just 'Slant' and 'Fade' included ... and not necessarily in that order (ie., can be 'Fade' and 'Slant' or 'Slant' and 'Fade).

Comment: So in your current example, row 3?

Comment: Row 3 includes other things than just 'Slant' and 'Fade.' The data includes 18,551 rows. I am looking for those observations under `Route' that include JUST Fade and Slant ... nothing else.

Comment: When you say JUST Fade and Slant, what all can it have?  Does it include `-` or space etc?  Please when you show an example, show both negative and postive cases with expected output so that it is easier

Comment: I added some more optioins based on asssumptions.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah. Thanks for helping me out ... again! I added a reproducible example as well as the desired outcome to the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` to split the data on comma and select those `GameID` and `EventID` which has only `Slant` and `Fade` values in them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Route, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(GameID, EventID) %>%
  filter(all(Route %in% c('Slant', 'Fade'))) %>%
  summarise(Route = toString(Route))
```

The above would look for an exact match and will not match words like `Fade - Back Shoulder`. In case you want to do string matching use `str_detect` or `grepl`.

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(Route, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(GameID, EventID) %>%
  filter(all(str_detect(Route, 'Slant') & str_detect(Route, 'Fade'))) %>%
  summarise(Route = toString(Route))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a pattern to detect in either direction

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
route.data$Route[6] <- "Fade - Slant"
route.data %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Route, 
        "(\\bSlant\\b.*\\bFade\\b)|(\\bFade\\b.*\\bSlant\\b)")& 
         str_count(Route, "\\w+") == 2)
  GameID EventID        Route
6   2793      60 Fade - Slant
```

---

Or it can be multiple expressions

```
route.data %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Route, "\\bFade\\b"),
         str_detect(Route, "\\Slant\\b"),
         str_count(Route, "\\w+") == 2)
 GameID EventID        Route
6   2793      60 Fade - Slant
```

---

Or if we want to check only rows having intended words, extract words, check if they are the only one

```
library(purrr)
route.data$Route[5] <- "Fade - Slant, Fade"
route.data %>%
 filter(map_lgl(str_extract_all(Route, "\\w+"), ~  
       all(unique(.x) %in% c("Fade", "Slant"), na.rm = TRUE)))
   GameID EventID              Route
5   2793      55 Fade - Slant, Fade
6   2793      60       Fade - Slant
```

#### data

```
route.data <- structure(list(GameID = c(2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 
2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L, 2793L), EventID = c(15L, 25L, 45L, 
50L, 55L, 60L, 65L, 70L, 85L, 95L), Route = c("Fade - Back Shoulder, Curl, Go/Fly, Out, Curl", 
"Go/Fly, Curl, Dig, Check & Release", 
"Fade, Swing - Left, Slant, Dig, Curl", 
"Jet Sweep Pass, Swing - Right", 
"Corner, Curl, Post, Curl, Slant", 
"Sluggo, Post, Curl, Chip - Flat, Flat - Left", "Go/Fly, Seam, Deep Cross, Dig, Flat - Right", 
"Curl, Dig, Post, Chip - Flat", "Curl, Seam, Curl, Dig, Curl", 
"Screen - RB")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: See my above comment. While what you are providing DOES find those observations with 'Slant' and 'Fade' included, I am looking for any possible entries in the 18,551 rows of data that includes JUST 'Slant' and 'Fade.'

Comment: @bcongelio so you showed an example where there is no positive match?

Comment: OK ... let's try to match row #9 ... 'Curl, Seam, Curl, Dig, Curl '

Comment: @bcongelio it doesn't have any Fade or Slant.

Comment: @bcongelio well, my `map` solution gives exactly the same output as your expected.  Anyway